# C# - How to get complement of two lists without identifiers

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have two lists of the same type.  That type does not have an identifier or any other guaranteed way to programatically distinguish.

- List A: {1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 8, 8, 8}
- List B: {1, 3, 5, 8}

I want the items from A that are not in B.

- Desired Result: {2, 2, 8, 8}

If the types had identifiers, I could use a statement like the following...

```
var result = listA
      .Where(a => listB.Where(b => b.Id == a.Id).Count() == 0)
      .ToList();
```

So far, the only way I can do this is with a loop where I add each item the number of times it doesn't appear in the original list.

```
foreach (var val in listB.Select(b => b.val).Distinct())
{
  var countA = listA.Where(a => a.val == val).Count();
  var countB = listB.Where(b => b.val == val).Count();
  var item = listA.Where(a => a.val == val).FirstOrDefault();

  for (int i=0; i<countA-countB; i++)
    result.Add(item);
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

**EDIT**: 
Here is a simplified version of the object in the lists.  It's coming from a Web service that's hitting another system.

```
public class myObject
{
  public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }
  public decimal SomeNumber; { get; set; }
  public bool IsSomething { get; set; }
  public string SomeString { get; set; }
}
```

The data I am receiving has the same values for SomeDate/SomeString and repeated values for SomeNumber and IsSomething.  Two objects might have equal properties, but I need to treat them as distinct objects.

Comment: Can we use LISP instead of C#?

Comment: You say you have no way to compare items and then in your second example you compare them by `val`. Please explain.

Comment: @Shaded: Throw it out there, if there's no solution for C# then at least you've got something. :)

Comment: @Kent: No way to compare equality between two items that have the same properties - yet they are different in the business.

Comment: Please post the type definition you're talking about. I don't understand how you want to determine whether items are "same" (to remove them) if you say they can't be compared. Do you want to compare the references?

Comment: Well, `==` doesn't check the fields, it checks the references.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this:

```
var listA = new List<Int32> {1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 8, 8, 8};
var listB = new List<Int32> {1, 3, 5, 8};
var listResult = new List<Int32>(listA);

foreach(var itemB in listB)
{
    listResult.Remove(itemB);
}
```

Comment: tested result returned: {2, 2, 8, 8}

Comment: I was just about to post a solution with `Remove`, you beat me to it though good job. +1

Answer (score 1):

What am I missing?

> ```
> class Program
> {
>     static void Main(string[] args)
>     {
>         List<int> a = new List<int>();
>         a.Add(1);
>         a.Add(2);
>         a.Add(2);
>         a.Add(3);
>         a.Add(5);
>         a.Add(8);
>         a.Add(8);
>         a.Add(8);
>         List<int> b = new List<int>();
>         b.Add(1);
>         b.Add(3);
>         b.Add(5);
>         b.Add(8);
>
>         foreach (int x in b)
>             a.Remove(x);
>
>         foreach (int x in a)
>             Console.WriteLine(x);
>
>         Console.ReadKey(false);
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Collection initializers :-)

Comment: :D  but my post looks bigger!

Answer (score 0):

You could sort both lists and then iterate through them both at the same time.

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetComplement(IEnumerable<int> a, IEnumerable<int> b)
{
    var listA = a.ToList();
    listA.Sort();
    var listB = b.ToList();
    listB.Sort();
    int i=0,j=0;
    while( i < listA.Count && j < listB.Count )
    {
        if(listA[i] > listB[j]) {yield return listB[j];j++;}
        else if (listA[i] < listB[j]) {yield return listA[i]; i++; }
        else {i++;j++;}
    }
    while(i < listA.Count)
    {
        yield return listA[i];
        i++;
    }
    while(j < listB.Count)
    {
        yield return listB[j];
        j++;
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is "cleaner", but it should be more performant on large sets of data.

Answer (score 0):

Are the objects same instances in both lists? If so you can use `.Where(a => listB.Where(b => b == a).Count() == 0)`

Or

```
.Where(a => !listB.Any(b => b == a))
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have no way to compare equality.  It's literally an object with some strings/ints that can be repeated (although in real life they are unique objects).

Comment: `==` operator doesn't check equality, it compares references. It will return `true` for two references pointing at the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit nasty but it does what you want. Not sure about performance though.

```
var a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 8, 8, 8 };
var b = new List<int> { 1, 3, 5, 8 };

var c = from x in a.Distinct()
        let a_count = a.Count(el => el == x)
        let b_count = b.Count(el => el == x)

        from val in Enumerable.Repeat (x, a_count - b_count)
        select val;
```

Comment: I just checked the implementation of Enumerable.Except: It doesn't work well with duplicates, so the result here would be {2}, instead of the requested {2,2,8,8}

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you implement your own equality comparer for your `myObject`:

```
public class YourTypeEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<myObject>
{
    public bool Equals(myObject x, myObject y)

    public int GetHashCode(myObject obj)
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
var list1 = new List<myObj>();
var list2 = new List<myObj>()
list1.RemoveAll(i => 
    list2.Contains(list1), 
    new YourTypeEqualityComparer()
);
```

now `list1` contains result.